# How to prevent WPF Checkbox inside a Button from being checked by double-click?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF Button whose content has a bunch of controls including a CheckBox.

Currently Single-Click on the CheckBox fires the "Checked" event, that's fine.

What I don't like is that Double-Click also fires the "Checked" event.

Currently the Double-Click triggers both the CheckBox' "Checked" event and the Button's "DoubleClicked" event.

What I want is that the Double-Click on the CheckBox should only trigger the Button's event, not the CheckBox's event. The CheckBox should only be checked upon a Single-Click.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you trying to do might not make for the best user experience because you're going to have to implement a delay prior to processing a user's attempt to check the box.

Why?

Well, if you double click the checkbox, you want nothing to happen with the checkbox, you just want to pass control up to the button. That's totally understandable.

But what happens if you simply click the checkbox? At the moment you release the mouse button, you are going to expect the check mark to appear. But the system can't yet know that you don't plan to click again. So, it has to wait through the [DoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx) to determine that you in fact never double-clicked.

You have to weigh which is worse: delay when checking the checkbox vs. flicker when double-clicking the checkbox.

If you decide to go with the delay, you'll need to implement it yourself. Here's a basic procedure that should work:

1. Create a handler for CheckBox.PreviewMouseDown. Within this handler, disable the CheckBox and start a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) with an interval of [DoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx).
2. Meanwhile, create a handler for Button.MouseDoubleClick that sets a field, `_hasDoubleClicked`, to true.
3. When the timer goes off, enable the checkbox, and if `_hasDoubleClicked` is false, toggle the `IsChecked` of the checkbox. Also, set `_hasDoubleClick = false`.

As you can see this is not pretty. You might want to ask yourself if there is another way to achieve your goal with a different design. Do you *need* to use double-click in the first place?